# Throwing custom Java exceptions

Tags: java, exception, data-structures, linked-list

I am working on a homework assignment for a Java Data Structures class, and we have to build a program from a stack ADT using a linked list implementation. The professor has requested that we include a method called popTop() which pops the top element of the stack, and throws a "StackUnderflowException" if the stack is empty. From what I can gather this is an exception class that we have to write ourselves, and I am having some problems with it. If anyone could help me I would be extremely appreciative. Here is some of my code:

```
private class StackUnderflowException extends RuntimeException {

    public StackUnderflowException() {
        super("Cannot pop the top, stack is empty");
    }
    public StackUnderflowException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

That's the exception class I wrote, here is the beginning of the popTop() method that I have written thus far:

```
public T popTop() throws StackUnderflowException {
    if (sz <= 0) {
        throw new StackUnderflowException();
    }
}
```

I am getting errors suggesting that StackUnderflowException cannot be a subclass of RuntimeException, could anyone shed some more light on this? And within the method I'm getting errors saying StackUnderflowException is undefined.

Comment: Your constructors are private

Comment: Change the inheritance from `RuntimeException` (unchecked) to `Exception` (checked).

Comment: Changing to Exception still gives me the error "cannot subclass java.lang.Throwable

Comment: @xandergrzy have you tried **changing the constructors from private to public**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You constructors are private and you should extend `Exception`, not `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Took care of the constructor issue (thanks for catching that everyone!) but am still having a problem trying to subclass Exception as well as RuntimeException

Comment: It's an answer, you're not questioning OP :).

Comment: @xandergrzy it's not suitable to extend `RuntimeException` nor `Error` classes, they're intended to be thrown by the JVM, not by programmers. For example, if you have `Integer y = null; int i = y;` the code will compile fine but throw a `NullPointerException` (that extends `RuntimeException`), or `void blowStack() { blowStack(); }` will throw a `StackOverflowError` (that extends `Error`). More info: [Unchecked Exceptions — The Controversy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

Comment: is this an inner or nested class?

Comment: if its not an inner class it shouldn't be private either :/

Comment: @Steve what *should be* an inner class for you? And please, write `@name` when you're referring to someone in comments.

Comment: It was an inner class and that was my problem. I guess I was running into problems trying to make this an inner class when I was working with generics. Anyway, got it solved. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code
1.Your customised Exception class is private
2. It extends runtime exception where it should be entensing the superclass Exception

You can create custom exception as is given below:

public class StackUnderflowException extends Exception{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public StackUnderflowException(){

}
/**
 * The constructor wraps the exception thrown in a method.
 * @param e the exception instance.
 */
public StackUnderflowException( Throwable e) 
{
    super(e);
}
/**
 * The constructor wraps the exception and the message thrown in a method.
 * @param msg the exception instance.
 * @param e the exception message.
 */
public StackUnderflowException(String msg, Throwable e) 
{
    super(msg, e);

}

/**
 * The constructor initializes the exception message.
 * @param msg the exception message 
 */
public StackUnderflowException(String msg) 
{
    super(msg);
}
```